# How to write Hive hook to access meta data level event changes by extending MetaStoreEventListener

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, eventhandler, data-lake

I am interested in fetching hive meta data level events which are generally stored in hive server 2 - like event based triggers for partition addition, deletion, table addition and deletion, etc. 
There is already an abstract class MetaStoreEventListener but I am unable to find a solid implementation of the same to access all Meta data related informations. Can you guys give me some insight in the right directions ?

Comment: Do you in particular intend to use the MetaStoreEventListener?

Comment: You can also have a look at the HDFS listeners, maybe, that could solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best wake is to create your own handler utility or framework to wrap around the traditional NotificationListener class (which extends the MetaStoreEventListener class) in the hcatalog package.

If you decide to solely use the NotificationListener class, then the following inbuilt listeners are readily available for usage:

1. Partitions (Add-onAddPartition, Alter-onAlterPartition, Drop-onDropPartition)
2. Databases (Create-onCreateDatabase, Drop-onDropDatabase)
3. Tables (Create-onCreateTable, Alter-onAlterTable, Drop-onDropTable)

Additionally, you can independently explore the HDFS package handlers. Or, on a more advanced side, write your own independent framework encapsulating the default event handlers provided by HCatalog and HDFS.

Comment: Sure, I will explore myself more on the suggested patterns.